# What is an example of a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ where the interior is not connected?

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual metric, could this be an open disk, e.g. $ \{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 \le 2\}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: an open disk is path-connected, hence connected...

Answer (score 1):

Two disks a unit apart, joined by a line. The line disappears when you take the interior.

Comment: You could also have two disks which meet at a single point on the boundary (this is what you get if you shrink the line between the two disks).